# I dont know why my setInterval is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quick question. Can anyone tell me why this code is not working? It is supposed to rotate 3 images in a banner on a website, but it only does it once. Thank you

```
    <body onload ="setInterval(changeImage, 3000 );">

      <script>
     var cont = 1;

    function changeImage(){


    switch (cont)
    {
      case 1:
      document.getElementById("grandImage").src = "Images/Banner/jirafa.jpg";
      cont += 1;
      break; 
      case 2:
      document.getElementById("grandImage").src = "Images/Banner/leo.jpg";
      cont += 1;
      break; 

      default:
        document.getElementById("grandImage").src = "Images/Banner/lion.jpg";
        cont=0;

    }



    </script>


    }
```

Comment: where's `cont` defined

Comment: just before the function is a global variable

Answer (score 2):

Your closing bracket for the function `changeImage` is outside of the `</script>`.

```html
    <body onload ="setInterval(changeImage, 3000 );">

      <script>
     var cont = 1;

    function changeImage(){


    switch ()
    {
      case 1:
      document.getElementById("grandImage").src = "Images/Banner/jirafa.jpg";
      cont += 1;
      break; 
      case 2:
      document.getElementById("grandImage").src = "Images/Banner/leo.jpg";
      cont += 1;
      break; 

      default:
        document.getElementById("grandImage").src = "Images/Banner/lion.jpg";
        cont=0;

    }

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: As **Grant** said, your closing bracket for the function **changeImage** is outside of the **</script>**. +1 to Grant [Here is your code working](https://jsfiddle.net/FacuCode/9qgazzLa/)

Answer (score 0):

In default you are assigning `0` to `cont`, and you don't have a case for `0`, this way it comes back to `default` again. Setting `cont=1` in `default` will fix it.